# How to dynamically update other row fields in a KendoUI grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, angularjs-directive, kendo-grid

In my KendoUI datasource, I have the following defined:

```
    change: function (e) {
        if (e.action === "itemchange") {
            // auto-format Display As
            var geoDisplay, geoUrl;
            if (e.items[0].GeoState.length > 0) {
                geoDisplay = e.items[0].GeoCity + ", " + e.items[0].GeoState;
            } else {
                geoDisplay = e.items[0].GeoCity;
            }
            //this.dataItem(this.select()).GeoDisplay = geoDisplay;

            e.items[0].GeoCity = "updated: " + e.items[0].GeoCity;  // visually updates if editing this field
            e.items[0].GeoDisplay = geoDisplay;  // field is not updated
        }
        console.log("change: " + e.action);
        console.log(e);
        // do something else with e
    },
```

Essentially I want to update other fields on a row being edited based on a field's input.

In this example, GeoCity is updated.  The `itemchange` event is fired and only the GeoCity field gets updated with the new value.  However I can see from the data that the other fields' data have been updated.

I have tried doing a .sync() and a few other methods to get this to appear, but no luck so far.

Incidentally, my grid is defined within an AngularJS directive and it's `onEdit` event isn't what I'm looking for, as I want the events that fire when each field is updated, not the whole row.

How can I get the other fields to visually update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by placing the following code in the data source code:

```
    change: function (e) {
        if (e.action === "itemchange") {
            // auto-format Display As
            var thisRow = $("#accountGeoLocationEditorGrid tbody").find(".k-grid-edit-row");

            // update geo display 
            if (e.field === "GeoCity" || e.field === "GeoState") {
                var geoDisplay, geoUrl;
                if (e.items[0].GeoState.length > 0) {
                    geoDisplay = e.items[0].GeoCity + ", " + e.items[0].GeoState;
                } else {
                    geoDisplay = e.items[0].GeoCity;
                }

                if (e.items[0].GeoDisplay.length == 0) {
                    e.items[0].GeoDisplay = geoDisplay;
                    thisRow.find("input[name=GeoDisplay]").val(geoDisplay);
                }
            }
        }
```

I was really looking for another way to do this, as I don't really want to be doing DOM lookup, etc in a defined datasource.

Other suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the grid `refresh()` method? At the end of your changes in the `change` event, call this line *(with your grid's correct id)*:

```
$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
```

I've tested this on my grid and kendo's samples and it works fine like this. You are editing the datasource but the grid is not aware of the extra changes you have done, except the cell that was edited. Calling refresh will update all the cells on the grid to reflect the datasource.